# Search in files using combined keywords in Sublime Text Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is it possible to search and find combined keywords in sublime text editor.? I'm using Sublime 2 Text Editor and i want to search particular keywords combined. Consider If there is 4 html files residing in a directory and each files contains a html tag with common class name = "header-text" and a unique class name ="header-text-1", "header-text-2", "header-text-3", "header-text-4" and with some other classes.

```
<h1 class="header-text header-text-1 ... ... ..."></h1> in file1.html
<h1 class="header-text header-text-2 ... ... ..."></h1> in file2.html
<h1 class="header-text header-text-3 ... ... ..."></h1> in file3.html
<h1 class="header-text header-text-4 ... ... ..."></h1> in file4.html
```

Is it possible to search and find by " '**header-text**' && '**header-text-1**' " combined in Sublime Search field (Find in files Ctrl+Shift+F ).

Please help me to find out the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a solution for you would be to use regex. In your (trivial) example you would search for something like

```
header-text.*header-text-[0-9]
```

This would match for content like

```
<h1 class="header-text header-text-1 ... ... ..."></h1>
<h1 class="header-text not-interesting-class header-text-2 ... ..."></h1>
```

If you want the whole line

```
^.*header-text.*header-text-[0-9].*$
```

You may try out some regex at [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/)